# Mapper side OutOfMeory

Tags: java, hadoop, memory-management, mapreduce, heap-memory

I'm facing heap space OutOfMemory error during my Mapper side cleanup method, where i'm reading the data from inputStream and converting it into byte array using IOUtils.toByteArray(inptuStream);

I know i can resolve it by increasing the max heap space(Xmx), but i should be having enough heap space(1Gb) already. I found the below info on debugging(approximate space value),

```
runtime.maxMemory() - 1024Mb
runtime.totalMemory - 700Mb
runtime.freeMemory - 200Mb
```

My block size is 128 Mb and i'm not adding any additional data to it on my RecordReader. My output size from the mapper wont be more than 128 Mb.
And also i saw the available bytes in inputStream(.available()) which is provided an approximate value of 128 Mb.

I'm also a bit confused about the memory allocation of JVM. Let's say I set my heap space value as Xms-128m;Xmx-1024m. My tasktracker has 16Gb RAM and already I've 8jobs(8JVM) running in that tasktracker. Lets assume that the tasktracker can allocate only 8.5 Gb RAM for JVM and it'll use the rest for it's internal purpose. So we have 8.5Gb RAM available and 8 tasks are running which is currently using only 6Gb RAM. Is it possible for a new task be assigned to the same task tracker since already 8 tasks are running which might require 8Gb in which case the new task wont be able to provide user requested heap size(1Gb) if required.

PS: I know that not all heap needs to be in RAM(paging). My main question is, will the user be able to get the maximum requested heap size in all scenario?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some Mapper code

Comment: @ChrisGerken: Sorry for the delay. I'll share the code snippet at the earliest.